# Atom Editor change bracket, brace colour?

Tags: colors, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I want to use the [solarized-light theme for Atom Editor](https://github.com/atom/solarized-light-syntax)

I managed to change the background colour, and can't find where to change the bracket, brace colours

I tried `.brace { color: hsl(168, 100%, 65%); }` But it's not it. All brackets and braces (I mean curly braces, parentheses, square brackets) are red, which is really distracting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So after many tries and research I think the best way is to open the editor in Developer Mode i.e. View->Developer->Open in Dev Mode....

Then open your code and with the right click you can Inspect Element just like in Mozilla Firefox, you can try changing styles live or find the .css file and changes properties there.

Restart Atom after making changes.

Comment: You don't need to restart Atom - there's (by default) a package called "dev-live-reload" installed, which reloads all the styles and packages. You can find it either in the "Packages" menu or invoke it via Cmd-Ctrl-Shift-R.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom stylesheet (styles.less) you could add

```
atom-text-editor::shadow .brace {
  color: hsl(168, 100%, 65%);
}
```

It should even reload the style on save.

Comment: It's not working. It only affects some braces selectively for some reason.

Comment: But whe you do .line then it has an effect on all types of braces, but also var names.